# How can I simulate random points on a brick file with 218 bands?

Tags: r, raster, point

I use the code below to get random points, but when I try to simulate them with the plot, 2-3 of them are going always out of my map plot. The problem is that my image is not a square. I don't know how I can filter in a better way to get all the random points on the map. The data I am using can be downloaded from the Enmap-toolbox in the examples for free.
[map plot with random points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPOFh.png)

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(terra)
rasterbrick<- brick("C:\\Users\\magai\\Desktop\\master thesis\\Example Alpis\\L2A_Alps_3_land\\ENMAP01-____L2A-DT000326721_20170626T102029Z_003_V000204_20200407T104257Z-SPECTRAL_IMAGE.TIF")
# Convert RasterBrick to SpatialPixelsDataFrame
spdf <- as(rasterbrick, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
set.seed(123) # set random seed for reproducibility
# generate 10 random points
n <- 10
xy_rand <- data.frame(x = runif(n, xmin(rasterbrick ), xmax(rasterbrick )), 
                      y = runif(n, ymin(rasterbrick ), ymax(rasterbrick )))
plotRGB(rasterbrick, r = 3, g = 2, b = 1, axes = TRUE, stretch = "lin")
# add random points to the plot
points(xy_rand, col = "red", pch = 10)
```

I tried a lot of code but still cannot figure out how I can implement this inside R.